# Why does the normal distribution describe data collected in real life so well?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$$
P(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left( - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$

Is there any intuition behind choosing $e^{-x^2}$ instead of some other function?

Comment: ??? What _definition_ of "normal" do you have in mind?

Comment: I don't think I get your question but I think it's this kind: [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Boxplot_vs_PDF.svg/350px-Boxplot_vs_PDF.svg.png) (Updated the question with the specific equation I'm talking about)

Comment: Words in math have _definitions_. The _definition_ of normal _says_ the distribution is exponential... You can't explain definitions, because they really don't say anything, they're just agreements about what some word will mean.

Comment: Are you thinking of the normal distribution as the limit of a sequence of iid variables, akin to CLT?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without you having more details on what you mean by the normal distribution. When I say this I don't mean the literal form, instead what I mean is what should one expect from a normal distribution? What constraints does such a distribution have? Over what range should it be valid?

Answer (score 1):

The question, at least in the way you asked it, really doesn't make much sense, because that funny exponential formula is the *definition* of "normal".

Your comments sound like you sort of don't get what I'm getting at here. An analogy: Suppose someone asked this:

**Q:** How do you prove that a triangle has three sides?

The answer would be this:

**A:** Huh? Having three sides is what it *means* to be a triangle!

Now, it may well be that the question you meant to ask makes more sense. But we can't tell, all we can see is what you actually wrote...

Answer (score 0):

The derivation of the Normal Distribution (Gaussian Distribution) should answer your question; it also explains why there is a pi and so forth:

https://www.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/papers/Normal/default.html